# Does David Lynch's eerie atmosphere (closer to german "Unheimlich"), have a definition and clear origin?

Tags: film-techniques, first-appearance, terminology, david-lynch

One aspect that all of lynch's films have is that eerie feeling that something is not quite right, but I find that atmosphere to be different from pure surrealism. Did Lynch start this? Or does it have origins in earlier films? I think the best example of this style is his short series "Rabbits", but I haven't seen a similar tone in older movies and I have never seen a definition for this style.